# CruiseControl.Net - not able to see Project Statistics

Tags: build-server

I've made a reinstallation of the buildserver and can no longer see the standard graphs of project statistics. The error message shown is

"Missing/Invalid statistics reports. Please check if you have enabled the Statistics Publisher, and statistics have been collected atleast once after that."

To the best of my knowledge, the ccnet.config file has not been changed in this respect and by inspection it is verified that I have a Statistics / statisticsList-section for the project. Furthermore, the values appear in the Artifacts\statistics.csv and Artifacts\report.xml files.

My guess would then be StatisticsGraph.xslt, which I have copied fresh from distribution to both Server\xlst and WebDashboard\xslt (why are they located in both places, by the way!?). Rebuild and check - still same error message.

Any hints to how to debug this would be appreciated!

Comment: Did you re-installed the same version? Or did you upgrade your version of CC.NET?

I went from 1.4.x to the 1.5.x branch and had to change a bunch of stuff in the config files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In version 1.4.3, there was a breaking change made to improve performance. An upgrade from a prior version to this version or later will require a manual modification to the report.xml file(s).  See the [release notes](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/CCNet+1.4.3+Release+Notes) for details.